# Bit strings of length $n$ in which any two consecutive $1$'s are separated by an even number of $0$’s

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the number of bit strings of length $n$ in which any two consecutive $1$'s are separated by an even number of $0$’s

My attempt:

Let $a_n$ be the required number

Take two cases:

- The string ends with $1$. In this case, the string must end with $001$. Number of such strings is $a_{n-3}$
- The string ends with $0$. Number of such strings is $a_{n-1}$

Mistake which I found but can't fix in my approach:

For $n=5$, $10$ is a valid length 2 string, appending $001$ doesn't give a valid length $5$ string.

Comment: string ending with $1$ can end with $11, 111, 1111, \dots $ also

Comment: Is a string like $00010011000010$ valid?  That is, can we have an even number of $0$s between any two consecutive ones, but an odd number of zeroes at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: @ab123 No, there has to be atleast 2 zeroes between two ones

Comment: @Michael Lugo Yes, those are valid

Comment: The answer is give the recurrence relation $T ( n ) = T ( n - 1 ) + T ( n - 2 ) + 1 , n \geq 2$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. Use the graph as in my previous answer, but don't bother with the starting state $S$, we can start at $A$ (we start with no zeros and then can have a zero or a one so it's OK). The graph looks like this:

[image: graph for finding which binary strings to reject and which approve]

Let's define $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n, e_n$ to be the number of walks on the graph that start from $A$ and after $n$ steps end up in $A, B, C, D, E$. What we want to calculate is the total number of approved strings:

$$x_n = a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n.$$

We notice these facts:

- $a_n = 1$
- $b_n = b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}$, and $b_0=0, b_1=b_2 = 1$
- $c_n = c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}-c_{n-4}$, and $c_0=c_1=0, c_2=c_3=1$
- $d_n = c_{n-1}$, and $d_0=0$

The first is obvious, since only the string $00\dots0$ can end up in $A$.
Also, the last since we can only arrive to $D$ from $C$.

Let's prove the other two inductively on $n$. First notice a helpful equation from the fact that we can arrive to $C$ from $B$ or from $D$:

- $\pmb{c_{m}} = b_{m-1} + d_{m-1} = \pmb{b_{m}+b_{m-1}-1}$, since $b_{m} = d_{m-1}+1$ (remember $a_m = 1$)

Let's now do the induction step for $b_{n+1}$:

$$b_{n+1} = a_{n}+ d_{n} = 1 + c_{n-1} = b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$$

Then for $c_{n+1}$. I found it easier to start with what we want, that is:

$$c_n+c_{n-1}-c_{n-3} \\
= b_n+b_{n-1}-1 + b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-1 - (b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}-1)\\
= b_n+b_{n-1}-1 + b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-1 - b_{n-1} +1 \\
= b_n-1+ b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}\\
= b_n-1+ b_{n+1}\\
= c_{n+1}.
$$

The base cases can be checked easily (for example with the matrix approach), here are how the sequences begin

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28...
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 15, 20, 27, 36, 48...
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 15, 20, 27, 36...
```

Then finally we also find a recursion for the sum of these, it is actually the same recurrence as for $c$ and $d$

> $$x_n = x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}-x_{n-4} \text{ and } x_0=1, x_1=2, x_3=3$$

Let's prove this with induction and also here it's easier to start with the right hand side. The $c$ and $d$ terms gather nicely, $a$ is just the $1$ that survives and noticing that $b_{n}-b_{n-3}=b_{n-2}$ and then that $b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}=b_{n}$ proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

Form a graph with $6$ nodes: $S, A, B, C, D, E$.

- $S$ the starting state (we're here when the string is empty)
- $A$ a state for beginning zeros
- $B$ a state where you have just gotten a one (and the string isn't already rejected)
- $C$ counting zeros after a one, have odd amount
- $D$ counting zeros after a one, have even amount
- $E$ the rejecting state

And the transition matrix, when indexed by this order of states (check each transition and justify them yourself)

$$ P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now $a_n = 2^n-P^n_{S, E}$. That is, we are looking for the top-right element of $P^n$, it gives the number of walks of length $n$ on the graph that end up in the rejecting state and start from the state $S$.

We can diagonilize $P$ to solve for a formula. Eigenvalues are

$\lambda_1 = 2$
$\lambda_2 \approx 1.32472$
$\lambda_3 = 1$
$\lambda_4 \approx 0.662359 + 0.56228 i$
$\lambda_5 = \bar{\lambda_4}$
$\lambda_6 = 0$

Here $\lambda_2, \lambda_4$ and $\lambda_5$ are the roots of $x^3-x-1$ which we get by dividing the exact roots away from the characteristic polynomial: $\frac{x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 - 2x}{x(x-1)(x-2)}$.

But then you would need to solve the eigenvectors and the inverse of that matrix and for me it looks pretty messy. Anyway, I think the sequence $a_n$ is [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A023434) and there a recurrence is given and from that it is easier to solve for the formula (for example via generating functions).